# How to avoid repeating query in loop for fetching data

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am sending sites details in list of dictionary format. Where some fields (three types payments with different payment statuses) we are fetching from other tables.
Right now for each iteration of loop three queries are executing.

I have mentioned below lines which are executing for each iteration

In below code I am trying to get all main payment amount and summing that amount.
Also there are some statuses of payment like payment raised, payment approved, payment completed.

```
main_payment_raised = sum(mainPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],approvalStatus='Waiting').values_list('quotation',flat=True))
main_payment_approved = sum(mainPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],approvalStatus='Approved',paymentStatus='Waiting').values_list('quotation',flat=True))
main_payment_paid = sum(mainPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],paymentStatus='Confirm',approvalStatus='Approved').values_list('quotation',flat=True))


partial_payment_raised = sum(partialPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],approvalStatus='Waiting').values_list('amount',flat=True))
partial_payment_approved = sum(partialPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],approvalStatus='Approved',paymentStatus='Waiting').values_list('amount',flat=True))
partial_payment_paid = sum(partialPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],paymentStatus='Confirm',approvalStatus='Approved').values_list('amount',flat=True))
extra_payment_raised = sum(extraPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],approvalStatus='Waiting').values_list('amount',flat=True))
extra_payment_approved = sum(extraPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],approvalStatus='Approved',paymentStatus='Waiting').values_list('amount',flat=True))
extra_payment_paid = sum(extraPaymentVendor.objects.filter(systemId=site['systemId'],paymentStatus='Confirm',approvalStatus='Approved').values_list('amount',flat=True))
```

This entire functionality is consuming more time.
Is there any optimized way to get result in minimum complexity

P.S. I am using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [**`conditional annotation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). For example:

```
from django.db.modles import Sum, Case, IntegerField

mainPaymentVendor.objects.filter(
    systemId=site['systemId']
).annotate(main_payment_raised=Sum(
    Case(
        When(approvalStatus="Waiting", then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
).annotate(main_payment_approved=Sum(
    Case(
        When(approvalStatus="Approved", then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
).annotate(main_payment_paid=Sum(
    Case(
        When(approvalStatus="Confirm", then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
).values('main_payment_raised', 'main_payment_approved', 'main_payment_paid')
```